# multidimensional compare two array

Tags: php

I have two arrays

```
$array1 = array(0=>array('mac'=>'mac0','geo'=>'geo0'),1=>array('mac'=>'mac1','geo'=>'geo1'),
2=>array('mac'=>'mac2','geo'=>'geo2')...);


$array2 = array(0=>array('id'=>'id0','gname'=>'gname0'),1=>array('id'=>'id1','gname'=>'gname1'),
2=>array('id'=>'id2','gname'=>'gname2')...);
```

I want to compare the two arrays for the first array value mac and second array value gname

if value of geo is available in the value of gname then update else do note update else do

not update

for example 
if a value of an array is available in any array in array2 then 
UPDATE

else do not update

Answer (score -2):

Here wrote code:

```
    $array1 = array(0=>array('mac'=>'mac0','geo'=>'geo0'),1=>array('mac'=>'mac1','geo'=>'geo1'),
2=>array('mac'=>'mac2','geo'=>'geo2'));


$array2 = array(0=>array('id'=>'id0','gname'=>'gname0'),1=>array('id'=>'id1','gname'=>'gname1'),
2=>array('id'=>'id2','gname'=>'gname2'));

function gluearray($ar1, $ar2) {
    foreach($ar2 as $key=>$value) {
        if(isset($ar1[$key])) {
            if(is_array($ar1[$key])) {
                $ar1[$key] = gluearray($ar1[$key], $value);
            } else {
                if($ar1[$key]!==$value) {
                    $ar1[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $ar1[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $ar1;
}
print_r(gluearray($array1, $array2));
```

result:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [mac] => mac0 [geo] => geo0 [id] => id0 [gname] => gname0 ) [1] => Array ( [mac] => mac1 [geo] => geo1 [id] => id1 [gname] => gname1 ) [2] => Array ( [mac] => mac2 [geo] => geo2 [id] => id2 [gname] => gname2 ) )